# can we save key value pair extracted from the document using aws sdk textract java v2 to seprate database in sqlyog? if yes what is the process?

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, sqlyog, amazon-textract

what will be the process to save output from aws sdk textract java v2 in seprate database sqlyog?

i am using intellij for coding to extract key value pair from aws textract i want save my output or extracted key and value in sqlyog table.

I  made table in sqlyog did basic connection required to connect to sqlyog its not working.What should i  try to save  my output in database.

i did recharge on aws documentation i did't find any api or method tho store data in seprate data base.
In extraction of key value pair from receipt i use expense api